# Using numpy to find all possible distance vectors in a coordinate grid

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, vectorization, linear-algebra

I'm trying to implement Fabian Timm's pupil tracking algorithm [http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/publikationen/pdfs/TiBa11b.pdf] and the equation requires that I find all possible distance vectors within a coordinate grid. My implementation isn't working correctly, and I think it's because of this step. I know I should speed up my implementation using broadcasting, but any insight into other possible improvements would be appreciated. I would also be curious to know any tricks to testing code like this. Did I do this right?

```
eye_len = np.arange(eye.shape[0]) # this is usually in the range of 30-40
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(eye_len,eye_len) # coordinates of every point in the eye image
X1,X2 = np.meshgrid(xx.ravel(),xx.ravel())
Y1,Y2 = np.meshgrid(yy.ravel(),yy.ravel())
Dx,Dy = [X1-X2,Y1-Y2]
Dlen = np.sqrt(Dx**2+Dy**2)
Dx,Dy = [Dx/Dlen, Dy/Dlen] #normalized
```

Comment: Look at functions in [scipy.spatial.distance](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html).

Comment: Thanks! I did, but that just returns a flat array. I'd like each row in the matrix to be all possible distance vectors from one pixel in my image. I need to dot my distances with the gradient of the image.

Comment: You can use the `squareform` function there to convert the flat array into a square distance matrix.

Comment: Will it be in the proper order, where each row can be reshaped into a matrix of distances to one point?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.  Each row will be the distances to a single point.  The set of distances to one point is more naturally represented as a (1-D) array than as a matrix, but yes, you could get it as a 1xN matrix.

Comment: OK, thanks! I'll look into that. However, my question still hasn't been answered. Have I made a mistake in my code?

Comment: You didn't explain what problem you're having with your current implementation.

Comment: My current implementation isn't tracking my pupil correctly, and I think it's because of this section. I want to make sure that this section does what I expect it to do, which is to generate all direction vectors to every point in a matrix.